# Puppet MongoDb enabling authentication

Tags: mongodb, puppet

I'm working on enabling authentication using the [puppetlabs mongodb module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mongodb).

As the docs say, to enable authentication, I should add auth => true.
But in order for authentication to work, I [have to add a user to the admin database](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/), so I did that like so:

```
mongodb::db { 'admin':
  user          => 'adminuser',
  password_hash => 'a15fbfca5e3a758be80ceaf42458bcd8',
}
```

This works for the first run, but subsequent runs results in the error:

> Mongodb::Db[admin]/Mongodb_database[admin]: Could not evaluate:
>   Execution of '/usr/bin/mongo --quiet --eval
>   db.getMongo().getDBNames()' returned 252: Wed Mar 26 16:28:40 uncaught
>   exception: listDatabases failed:{ "errmsg" : "need to login", "ok" : 0
>   }

This makes sense, since it's unable to authenticate now to check if the admin database already exists.

How do you handle configuring mongodb password authentication with this module?

Comment: There is the [dba.stackexchangecom](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) site, you know. And Stack Overflow **is** intended for **programming** questions and answers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @NeilLunn This is more of a devops question. I posted it on ServerFault as well now. But it seems to be a bit of confusion as to where is best to post this kind of question. DBA only has 6 questions even mentioning puppet.

Comment: @bencoder A possibly related question was posted last month at https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/5307/mongodb-authtrue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this pull request (merged 23. okt 2015) might fix this issue: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb/pull/194

With this, you can supply admin username and password to server creation like this:

```
class {'::mongodb::server':
  auth           => true,
  create_admin   => true,
  admin_username => "admin",
  admin_password => "admin"
}
```

Now puppet should be able to authenticate against mongodb on subsequent runs.

Comment: We solved it a different way - just noticed this answer, it looks good so approving this one

Answer (score 1):

This is my complete manifest file that made my deployment work (on a Vagrant setup). I only wanted to install Mongo and it's what I achieved.

```
class {'::mongodb::server':
  #port    => 27017,  #the default port
  verbose => true,
  auth => true,
  bind_ip => ['0.0.0.0'] #Necessary for Vagrant to bind on the correct IP address instead of the loopback 127.0.0.1
}

#if we install a different port this did not work for me
mongodb::db { 'testdb':
  user          => 'user1',
  password_hash => 'a15fbfca5e3a758be80ceaf42458bcd8', #this means pass1
}

include '::mongodb::server'
```

Remember to include the following modules in your `modules` folder:

- https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb
- https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib (the first one depends on this one)

Comment: This is pretty much what we ended up doing. The intent of the original question though, was to enable admin authentication - which means it will require a username and password from the localhost, but this appears to be not possible as the puppet module relies on being able to access the server without a username/password in order to perform the setup.